# Prevent event propagation on row click and dialog in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

I'm using [material-ui](/questions/tagged/material-ui) and I have a table with a button inside. The button opens a Dialog and I need to be able to support clicking on the table row.
The problem is that with Portals (in react) - [the events are propagated](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11387), so clicking inside the Dialog (that was opened after clicking on the button) - the click event on the table-row will get fired.

This is the row:

```
<TableRow onClick={rowClick}>
  <TableCell>Content 1</TableCell>
  <TableCell>Row clicked {count} times</TableCell>
  <TableCell>
    <MyDialog />
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

This is the dialog:

```
<>
  <IconButton onClick={handleClickOpen}>
    <EditIcon />
  </IconButton>
  <Dialog disableBackdropClick open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
    <DialogTitle>Dialog</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>Some content</DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClose}>Save</Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</>
```

Here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-hofstadter-gzwll

And this is an animated gif that shows the issue:
[image]

I know I can set the "rowClick" on each cell (and leave the last cell without it) but this is just an example and I'm looking for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It took some time to find a proper solution, but the only way to prevent the propagation of the event was to add a "click" function on the dialog itself:

```
<>
  <IconButton onClick={handleClickOpen}>
    <EditIcon />
  </IconButton>
  <Dialog
    disableBackdropClick
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    onClick={handleDialogClick}
  >
    <DialogTitle>Dialog</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>Some content</DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
        Save
      </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</>
```

And have the handleClickDialog function stop the event propagation:

```
const handleDialogClick = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

Here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-violet-19uvd

Comment: LORD JESUS CHRIST THANKS FOR WRITING THIS SOLUTION HERE. GOD BLESS YA

Comment: You made me happy

Comment: @Mateusz happy to help! :)

Comment: Thanks here too -- I thought I had tried everything.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to add an `onClick` handler within `my-dialog.js`.

```js
const handleClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // doesn't do anything except stop the event
  };
```

and then add it to your `Dialog`:

```js
     <Dialog
        disableBackdropClick
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
```

Fork of your sandbox with the changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-chaplygin-lql5m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do it `e.stopPropagation();`. The dialog and edit icon is wrapped with row and row has click function.

I would ask you to check this https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-bassi-b9hev

I made some changes. It will open and close the dialog box.

In your existing implementation  icon is part of a dialog box which is wrong. you can check my code.

Hint:

```
 <TableBody>
            <TableRow onClick={rowClick}>
              <TableCell>Content 1</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Row clicked {count} times</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <IconButton onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
                  <EditIcon /> // I change it here
                </IconButton>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
...

      <MyDialog isOpen={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} />
```

**New DialogBox**

```
 <Dialog
      disableBackdropClick
      open={props.isOpen}
      onClose={() => props.onClose()}
    >
      <DialogTitle>Dialog</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>Some content</DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={() => props.onClose()}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => props.onClose()}>Save</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
```

Comment: Due to the structure of the application - the Modal must be inside the cell

Answer (score 0):

**you need to disable row event click for action column using stopPropagation 

which will fix the issue**

```
  const handlerActionColmunClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  };


    <TableBodyCell onClick={handlerActionColmunClick }>
                      <IconButton
                        aria-label="three-dot-action-menu"
                        aria-controls="customized-menu"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            onClick={handleActionMenuClick}
                          >
       ...........
    ...........
 ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent event propagation, change 'MyDialog' to a node at the same level or a higher level of 'TableRow' rather than being a child node

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my outer `Dialog` component already a click handler I didn't want to touch. Because events keep popping upwards, there's actually no need to intercept them right away. I found adding another wrapper component with the sole job to prevent event propagation to be easier to add in.

```
function EventBlocker({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return <span onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>{children}</span>;
}
```

Now just wrap this around whatever you are using. My project uses Radix, but this idea should be general to any React project.

```
    <EventBlocker>
        <Dialog open={dialogOpen} onOpenChange={setDialogOpen}>
             // more dialog components
        </Dialog>
    </EventBlocker
```